# how to boot from iso in openstack horizon

Tags: openstack, iso, openstack-nova

I'm trying to use horzon web page to build an instance from an ISO image, but it appears to show no disk in centos install configuration. while i choose to create new volume.

the general flow like below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The test openstack invironment is built with devstack on the latest branch. I upload with a centos iso downloaded from http://mirrors.163.com/centos/7.6.1810/isos/x86_64/, i followed the original workflow provided by horizon. But it seems failed.

webpage send follow data to horizon server

```
{  
   "availability_zone":"nova",
   "config_drive":false,
   "user_data":"",
   "disk_config":"AUTO",
   "instance_count":1,
   "name":"vm_boot_from_iso",
   "scheduler_hints":{  

   },
   "security_groups":[  
      "09f6bebe-3015-438d-8b4c-2d10b5d5998b"
   ],
   "create_volume_default":true,
   "hide_create_volume":false,
   "source_id":null,
   "block_device_mapping_v2":[  
      {  
         "source_type":"image",
         "destination_type":"volume",
         "delete_on_termination":true,
         "uuid":"0e49cc7a-593c-4a62-a05f-bdef63157d22",
         "boot_index":"0",
         "volume_size":10
      }
   ],
   "flavor_id":"d2",
   "nics":[  
      {  
         "net-id":"f9796914-00b5-4dfe-a7fa-4b2c1641d037",
         "v4-fixed-ip":""
      }
   ],
   "key_name":null
}
```

I was expecting through the installation i could find the disk provided by the workflow.

Comment: Do you want to run an instance as a normal VM? I mean, you want to use the nova console and expect to see the CentOS installer and then be able to run a manual installation?

Comment: Is is possible that the workflow of openstack horizon not support start instance from iso image

Comment: @AngelHumbertoVargas yes, but i can not find any disk from the manual installation  page.

Comment: if you don't mind about the disk format,  try a qcow2 centos7: https://cloud.centos.org/centos/7/images/

Comment: i am just struggling to start a vm with a iso image, haha